# how to get string between to character using inline method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know this is repetitive question, but I need help with small trick as it is not provided before.

I have data binding with inline if condition and I need to apply a small code of Substring in the same way "inline".

**my data binding snippet**

```
<textarea id="NoteForLogos" cols="20" rows="2">
    <%# (Request.QueryString["lang"] == null || Request.QueryString["lang"].ToString() == "e"? 
        Eval("EditableHtml"): Request.QueryString["lang"].ToString() == "a"? 
        Eval("EditableHtml_A") : Eval("EditableHtml_T")).ToString() %>
</textarea>
```

let's assume I have string like this.

```
var input = "bla bla bla bla [I need to display this] bla bla bla bla bla";
```

all I need to add inline Substring function to the above data binding code

like this ...

```
<%# (Request.QueryString["lang"] == null || Request.QueryString["lang"].ToString() == "e"? 
        Eval("EditableHtml"): Request.QueryString["lang"].ToString() == "a"? 
        Eval("EditableHtml_A") : Eval("EditableHtml_T"))
.ToString().Substring( ?.IndexOf("["), ?.IndexOf("]"))  %> //<==============
```

Note: I guess it can be done using (Lambda Expression)

Comment: So are you asking "how do I get the 'I need to display this' part of the string"?

Comment: @stuartd (exactly but inline)

Comment: Does this help? https://dotnetfiddle.net/T1epmc - but what does "but inline" mean?

Comment: @stuartd that is the same output as what I need but it can't be played in this condition as I can't but this code in data binding. I need it inline. that means I need input to be inline. using something like this **(x => x.tostring().IndexOf('[') + 1, x => x. Length -  x.tostring().IndexOf('[') + 1)**

Comment: but of course this is not fixed because I don't know how to use lambda expression

Comment: Is it guaranteed somewhere that `[` and `]` will exist in the string, with `]` always *after* `[`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this all in one line? That code is going to be a nightmare to debug, and multiple calls will have to be made to get the string and multiple `IndexOf` calls will have to be made for the same character. It would be best to get the string, then get the index of the characters, then get the substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see you want to do it in a single line of code, there are several ways to get this done *(Assuming your string will always follow the pattern you have
    mentioned and will not include extra block brackets)*.

Using `Split()` Method:

```
1) input.Split('[')?.LastOrDefault()?.Split(']')?.FirstOrDefault()
2) input.Split('[', ']')[1]
```

Using `Substring()` Method:

```
1) input.Substring(input.IndexOf('[') + 1, input.IndexOf(']') - input.IndexOf('[') - 1)
```

Using `Regex` Expression:

```
1) Regex.Match(input, @"\[([^)]*)\]")?.Groups[1]?.Value
```

Using `Linq` Expression:

```
1) new string(input.Skip(input.IndexOf('[') + 1).Take(input.IndexOf(']') - input.IndexOf('[') - 1).ToArray())
```

Or, in other way, you can create a static methon if you are using `aspx` pages then call it in the Expression. Something like this:

```
public static string ExtractValue(string input)
{
    var extractedValue = "";

    var splitted = input.Split('[');
    if(splitted != null && splitted.Length > 1)
    {
        var subSplitted = splitted[1].Split(']');
        if(subSplitted != null && subSplitted.Length > 0)
        {
            extractedValue = subSplitted[0];
        }
    } // This is just to elaborate that you can go multiline in cs page while calling a static method from your aspx page during data Eval.

    return extractedValue;
}
```

And I assume you will call it like this:

```
<%# 
    ExtractValue(
        (Request.QueryString["lang"] == null ||
            Request.QueryString["lang"].ToString() == "e"? 
            Eval("EditableHtml"): Request.QueryString["lang"].ToString() == "a"? 
            Eval("EditableHtml_A") : Eval("EditableHtml_T"))
        .ToString()
    )
%>
```

*PS:* Of course you will strongly need to cleanup your logic with query string params, Going multiline is always highly recommended because it drastically increases code readability.